# Como obtener el tipo de una funcion - typeid(function()) c++

Tags: c++, function, type, c++17

Quiero obtener el tipo de función para crear un mapa de funciones
Puede hacerlo sin crear una clase para no definir un tipo de datos por el usuario

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

void insercion()
{
  std::cout << "hola";
}

int main()
{
  //Type of data ??
  std::cout << "Tipo: " << typeid(insercion()).name() << "\n;
  //Salida: Tipo: v
  //Porque es de este tipo?
}
```

Yo quiero hacer esto
Ejemplo:

```
map<int,??> m_function = {
{1,insercion()},
{2,busqueda()}
}
```

Comment: Ya me equivoque de stack jaja

Comment: Quiero obtener el tipo de función para crear un mapa
Puede hacerlo sin crear una clase para no definir un tipo de datos por el usuario.Yo quiero crear un mapa de funciones se puede hacer. Que tipo de dato deberia poner

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> //Type of data ??
> std::cout << "Tipo: " << typeid(insercion()).name() << "\n;
> //Salida: Tipo: v
> //Porque es de este tipo?
> ```

el valor devuelto por `typeid().name()` no es estándar y puede, por tanto, variar de compilador en compilador. En este caso la `v` indica `void`, pero no es una solución portable.

> Quiero obtener el tipo de función para crear un mapa de funciones

El prototipo de tu función es `void func()`. Puedes usar `std::function` para almacenar un puntero a las funciones:

```
std::map<int, std::function<void()>> m_function = {
    {1,insercion()},
    {2,busqueda()}
};
```

La única restricción es que **todas** las funciones deben tener la misma firma que la indicada por `std::function`, en este caso no recibir parámetros y no devolver nada.

Answer (score 2):

> Quiero obtener el tipo de función [...]

Para obtener el tipo de cualquier dato, puedes usar `decltype` (**decl**ared **type**, tipo declarado).

```
using tipo = decltype(insercion);
```

> [...] para crear un mapa de funciones

Una vez tienes el tipo, puedes crear el mapa:

```
std::map<int, tipo *> funciones;
```

[Aquí](https://tio.run/##lY/BSsQwEIbPnacYENxGqmz32NZelhW8rCL1IAghJOkSaCelSQQpffaaSmXP3v4Z/u9jRg7DvewEXZblxpDsgtJYGev8qEVfw3XXi6EG@LJGYZunDCd0XhWFtMFjVSHnr2@npvngT@/nY/P8cuZ8Xe8@aVfivHGHf3NgyGMvDKUMJkiCM3TBVcZbfESlZee/B522OSsh@RXHO6sIZX@tuxrbQNJY0g6S6EimfRZfmLM15jEe1jiXAElrR0ylJedRBG/xdiOxuDpYxLbhwelYVilb2VH7MBLuS5iX5Qc) tienes un ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void f1() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void f2() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    using void_f = decltype(f1);
    std::map<int, void_f *> funciones
    {
        {0, f1},
        {1, f2},
    };

    for (const auto &funcion : funciones)
        funcion.second();

    return 0;
}
```